# Scalar argument to __call()

Tags: php

As per the syntax of the call function, it should expect
the name of the method and an array containing arguments

ie
     `__call(method_name,array_of_args)`

I passed a scalar to the second parameter and was trying to understand
how it works.

Below is the piece of code.

```
public function __call($method,$par)
{

if ($method=='display')
    {
    if (is_array($par[0]))
          {$this->displayarray($par[0]);}
    else
          {$this->displayscalar($par);}
    }
}

public function displayarray($par)
{
$temp=implode(',',$par);
echo $temp."<br />";
}  /*This works as expected*/

public function displayscalar($par)
{
$temo=implode(',',$par);
echo $temo."<br/>"; /* This line gives the scalar as the output*/
/*But why should $par be treated as an array?*/
echo $par."<br/>"; /*This line doesn't print anything, Why?*/
}

/*Below are the parameters supplied*/
$obj=new testoverride();
$obj->display('TestVector');
$obj->display(array(1,2,3,5,6));
```

I come from the C++ world of type conversions and have a difficulty in
understanding how PHP deals when a scalar is passed to expected array?

Insights appreciated !!

Comment: `var_dump($par);` --- if there is no `array` type hint in the function signature then this requirements is just *conventional*. That is - php will happily accept anything you pass as an argument.

Comment: "This line doesn't print anything, Why?" --- it does output `Array` since you're `echo`ing an array.

Comment: "I passed a scalar to the second parameter" --- you did not. It's php that passes an array of arguments. In the first case it's an array with one element: a string. In the second: an array with one nested array.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$this->displayscalar($par[0])`?  `$par` is an array of arguments that `display` was called with.  `__call()` is called *internally* by PHP.

Comment: @zerkms: Thanks for the insight Regarding `"I passed a scalar to the second parameter" --- you did not`, even if we do not use an array construct ie $obj->display(array('TestVector')) PHP should consider whatever passed as argument an array. isn't it?

Comment: @sjsam: nope. php passes an array of arguments. If `$this->foo(1, 2, 3)` - you've invoked a function with 3 arguments, so php will trigger a `__call` and pass an array with 3 elements.